# How to find/remove input in form by value?

Tags: jquery

How to find/remove input element in form by value ?

Comment: Do you want to remove all input elements that contain the value, or just the first one? Are the inputs we're talking about text boxes, radio buttons, drop down lists? Your question needs a lot of clarification before it can be answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to cover all the bases:

```
var matches = $('input').filter(function() { return this.value == 'what you want' });
matches.remove(); // If you want to remove them of course.
```

An [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) only sees things that have the `value` attribute set in the DOM so that won't see an `<input>` that has been updated with a [`val(x)`](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2) call, using a `filter` will see things that have been updated with `.val(x)`.

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/RVWu6/

Comment: That's the second time this particular nuance has got me... `:s`

Answer (score 0):

Making an initial guess at what you're trying to accomplish, you should probably take a look at this question:

[How can I select a hidden field by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065981/jquery-how-to-select-a-hidden-field-by-value)

The suggestion there is `$('input[value="Whatever"]')`

From there you can use the jQuery `remove` function: http://api.jquery.com/remove/

Comment: This selector doesn't work for `value`, unless the attribute of an element is explicitly set (in the HTML source, of by JavaScript).