# Selector doesn't work

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I've got a problem with my form validation:
I have two DIV-container each with two answers. I would like to validate wheter there is minimum checked one radio or there is a value in one text element.

But my jQuery selector doesn't work:

HTML:

```
<div class="mandatory">
    <input type="radio" value="1" name="answer1" /> Option 1
    <input type="radio" value="2" name="answer1" /> Option 2
</div>

<div class="mandatory">
    <input type="radio" value="1" name="answer2" /> Option 1
    <input type="text" name="answer2" />
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.mandatory').each(function(){
    var elem = $(this).find('input:checked, input:text[value!=""]');
    console.log(elem.attr('name')); //Always "answer2"
});
```

It returned the input element although it is empty.
Here is my code: http://fiddle.jshell.net/Pisi2012/n9S2Y/

Thanks for your help!

Comment: element = input, type = text and value should'nt be empty

Comment: @Bondye: Not exactly. See http://api.jquery.com/text-selector

Comment: answer2 returns undefined, undefined does not equal to ''

Answer (score 1):

Your input doesn't have a value attribute, so the ***attributes*** selector matches, as the value isn't an empy string, there just is no value ?

Change

```
<input type="text" name="answer2" />
```

to

```
<input type="text" name="answer2" value="" />
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/n9S2Y/2/)

Comment: `[value!=""]` is supposed to match `:not([value])`. See http://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/

Comment: @BoltClock - well, it doesn't. Adding a value attribute makes it work.

Comment: @BoltClock - in the docs it's `:not([attr="value"])`, and if there is no attribute it can't match an empty string for the value, as the value is undefined

Comment: `:not([attr="value"])` is covered by `:not([attr])` as well. Since the attribute isn't defined it can't match a value, so it has to match *not* having a value otherwise. I don't see how adding a `value` attribute would make your fiddle work - on the contrary it makes it *not* work.

Comment: exactly, I guess I just misunderstood your first comment?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
$('.mandatory').each(function(){
    var elem = $(this).find('input:checked, input[type="text"][value!=""]');
    console.log(elem.attr('name')); //Always "answer2"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What I assume is you need the list of `mandatory` divs, which does not satisfy the given condition, then try

```
var els = $('.mandatory').filter(function(){
    var $this = $(this);

    return !$this.find(':radio:checked').length && !$this.find(':text').filter(function(){return $.trim(this.value) != ""}).length
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/arunpjohny/kwKsY/)

Answer (score 0):

You could try Glyn Jones' solution from this other thread:

[How can I select a hidden field by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065981)

So it might look something like this:

```
var elem = $(this).find('input:checked, input:text').filter(function () { $(this).val() != '' });
```